# How to pass a icon and text to a button in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have to pass an icon and text to a button, and this button is in a component, and that component name is ReusableButton in my project. My problem is I have two more buttons with same button style, but the icon and text are different. So If I know how to pass an icon and text to a button, then I can resume that button component. I will share my code so please go through it once. Still, if I am not clear with my doubt please
put comment

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar/Navbar'
import Button from './Button/Button'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Button></Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is App.css

```
I didn't apply any css in App.css
```

This is Navbar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';


class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-6'>
                        <nav className="logoclass navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                            <a className='hyperlinkStyle' href='www.facebook.com'>
                                <img className='logoStyle' src='assets/images/logo.png' alt='logo'></img>
                            </a>
                            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

This is Navbar.css

```
/* logoStyle css starts here */
.logoStyle {
    width:103px;
    margin-top: -4%;
    margin-left: 88%;
}
/* logoStyle css ends here */

/* this css used to remove dots in li of ul, starts here */
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/* ends here */

/* helpStyle css starts here */
.helpStyle {
    color: #00b2d6;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: .75rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
/* helpStyle css ends here */

.lione {
    display: inline-block;
}

.litwo {
    display: inline-block;
}

.lithree {
    display: inline-block;
}

.border {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 1%;
}

.english {
    color: #524c61;
    font-size: .75rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: .75rem;
}

.flagStyle {
    height:.75rem;
    margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .25em;
    margin-top:-2.5%;
}

.rupeeStyle {
    margin-left: .5em;
    color: #b2aebd;
    font-size: .75rem;
}

.buttonStyle {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This is Button.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Button.css'
import ReusableButton from '../ReusableButton/ReusableButton';

class Button extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-12'>
                        <ReusableButton></ReusableButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Button
```

This is Button.css

```
I didn't apply any css in Button.css
```

I created this component to reuse, This is ReusableButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './ReusableButton.css';


class ReusableButton extends Component {
   render() {
       return(
           <div className='button'>
               <button type='button' class='btn-primary buttonStyle'>Click here</button>
           </div>
       )
   }
}

export default ReusableButton
```

This is ReusableButton.css

```
.buttonStyle {
    border: none;
}
```

My Goal is to pass Icon and text to a button.

Comment: Where do you want to put your reusable button text? Was it in `Click here`? And what is your Icon made of? bootstrap class or image import?

Comment: I created one component and I named it as ReusableButton. I have three buttons, In those three buttons I have different logo's and different text for each button. That's why I created a ResusableButton component to reuse it. I want to know is it possible to send Icon and text to ReusableButton Component using props?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm already writing my answer. I guess it will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `props` for this.
In your `Button.js`, pass the text you want to put in your reusable button like this

```
<ReusableButton btnText="yourText"></ReusableButton>
```

Then suppose your icons are images (not bootstrap glyphicons), you import all of them first and create a switch condition that will render the right icon according to your passed text.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ReusableButton.css';
//import your icons here
import Icon1 from './dir/icon1.png';
import Icon2 from './dir/icon2.png';
import Icon3 from './dir/icon3.png';

class ReusableButton extends Component {

   //this function will identify what icon to render
   renderIcon = () => {
     switch(this.props.btnText) {
       case 'yourText1': return <Icon1 />;
       case 'yourText2': return <Icon2 />;
       case 'yourText3': return <Icon3 />;
     }
   }

   render() {
       return(
           <div className='button'>
               <button type='button' class='btn-primary buttonStyle'>
                  {this.renderIcon} {this.props.btnText}
               </button>
           </div>
       )
   }
}

export default ReusableButton;
```

---

### **ANOTHER APPROACH**

Another way is pass the icon and text from the parent `Button` component as children like this

```
//import your icons at Button.js
import Icon1 from './dir/icon1.png';
import Icon2 from './dir/icon2.png';
import Icon3 from './dir/icon3.png';
```

Then pass it as children to your reusable button like this

```
<ReusableButton><Icon1 /> YourText1 </ReusableButton>
<ReusableButton><Icon2 /> YourText2 </ReusableButton>
<ReusableButton><Icon3 /> YourText3 </ReusableButton>
```

Then in your `ReusableButton.js`
Use it like this

```
render() {
       return(
           <div className='button'>
               <button type='button' class='btn-primary buttonStyle'>
                  {this.props.children}
               </button>
           </div>
       )
   }
```

Comment: NIce use of switch.

Comment: Is this *Reusable* Button? I don't think so. I usually pass icon url by props too.

Comment: @Antonio Thanks for pointing that out. I'll add another approach in my answer and see if which one is better.

Comment: How to Import Fontawsome Icons?

Comment: @Vamsi you need to install react icons like this `npm install react-icons --save` then you can now import fontawesome icons like this `import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';`. For more icon reference visit this site https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/icons/fa

Comment: How do you pass a react-icons icon via props?